# Definition of density of a finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have some finite measure $\mu$ on the Borel sets of $R$. It is then assumed that there exists a density for this measure. What does that mean?

I am only familiar with densities in the measure theoretic probability setting: a random variable $X$ with distribution $P^X$ has density $f$ if $f$ is a positive measurable function and it holds for all Borel sets  $B$ that $P^X(B)=\lambda(I_{B}f)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

In direct analogue, would it mean that there exists a positive measurable function $f$ such that $\mu(B)=\lambda(I_B f)$?

Comment: Assuming $\lambda(I_Bf)$ means $\int_B f\,d\lambda$, then yes, that is exactly what having having a density means.

Comment: So a finite measure having a density is always meant with respect to the lebesque measure? @MikeEarnest

Comment: Yes, that is the case. You _could_ talk about a measure $\mu$ having a density with respect to an arbitrary reference measure. For example, if $X$ has the Cantor distribution, then $P^X$ has a density with resect to $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, where $d=\log_3 2$. The density function is $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is in the Cantor set, $0$ otherwise. However, people do not usually do this.